# Create object with the name a property set to the contents of variable

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code snippet to create a class `payload`:

```
function setPointer(parent, attribute, children) {
    var url = 'https://api.xzy.com/1/classes/' + parent;
    var pointToObjects = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var pointToObject = {
            "__type":"Pointer",
            "className": childrenClass,
            "objectId":children[i]
        };
        pointToObjects.push(pointToObject);
    }

    var object = {
        attribute:{
            "__op":"AddRelation",
            "objects":pointToObjects
        }
    };
    var payload = JSON.stringify(object);
    var payload = {
        attribute:{
            "__op":"AddRelation",
            "objects":children
        }
    };

    var options = {
        'method': 'post',
        'contentType':'application/json',
        'headers': makeHeaders(),
        'payload': payload,
        'muteHttpExceptions':false
    };

    var jsonResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(jsonResponse.getResponseCode() + ': ' + jsonResponse);
}
```

How can I set the `attribute` and `children` properties of the `payload` object to the contents of the parameters `attribute` (e.g. "period") and `children` (e.g. "hgssgs", "eejss")?

I would like to create a HTTP request like the following:

```
curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: yyy" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxx" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"opponents":{"__op":"AddRelation","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Player","objectId":"Vx4nudeWn"}]}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm
```

Comment: Show how yours `attribute` and `children` inside the function are look like?

Comment: I have edited your code for better reading. Check if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `attribute` in the square brackets. It will automatically create new parameter for object with the name that stored in that string variable.

Here is an example:

```
var param = 'someParam';
var obj = {};
obj[param] = {
    val: 1
}
```

The result `obj` is as follows

```
{
    someParam: {
        val: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: vz_ I have updated my question, code sample and the HTTP request I would like to create.

Comment: My problem is that I do not know the name of the attribute variable beforehand. It could be 'var payload = {something: attribute…} or var payload = {something else: attribute}. I do not know on how to set the attribute key in the object initialization to the contents of a variable (contents can be 'something' or 'something else'.

Comment: But you have an argument `attribute` in the function (your first line): `function setPointer(parent, attribute, children)`. I mean that `attribute`, not the attribute by creating the `payload`. How it looks like?

Comment: This `attribute`
 is a string, e.g. 'periods'.